# A positive integer divisor of 12! is chosen at random. The probability that the divisor chosen is a perfect square?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

I came across this particular problem, 2020 AMC 10A Problem 15:

> A positive integer divisor of 12! is chosen at random. The probability that the divisor chosen is a perfect square can be expressed as *m/n*, where m and n are relatively prime positive integers. What is m + n?

**My Approach:** I found out that 12! can be represented as $\ 2^{10} . 3^5 . 5^2 . 7 . 11$. So, total no. of factors of 12! are $(10+1)(1+5)(1+2)(1+1)(1+1) = 792$. This must be the denominator.

Plus, the perfect square divisors can come only from $2^{10} . 3^4 . 5^2$.

**My Doubt:** How to find the no. of perfect square divisors ? Please give me a detailed explanation.

Edit: Can we take n = $2^{10} . 3^4 . 5^2$. and then find out the total number of factors of n? Will that work?

Comment: No, because  for example $2^3\cdot 5$ is a factor of $n$ and is not a square.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use $4^{5}\cdot 9^2\cdot 25^1$ : I will leave it to you to work out how.

Comment: Oh, then n = $4^5 . 9^2 . 25$ and since all these terms are perfect squares, we need to get all the factors i.e., there are 36 in total and so the probability would be 36/792 or 1/22, right? Thank you sir!

Comment: @Golden_Hawk I hope you can now see how to do a similar problem, for example with cubes, or with a higher factorial.

Answer (score 4):

Each divisor of $12!$ will be of the (unique) form $2^{a_1} \cdot 3^{a_2} \cdot 5^{a_3} \cdot 7^{a_4} \cdot 11^{a_5}$ with $a_1 \in \{0, \dots 10\} = [10]$ etc, so you have a bijection between divisors of $12$ and $[10] \times [5] \cdots$. Each number is a perfect square iff each $a_i$ is even, so this makes for $a_1$ $E(11/2)$ choices where $E$ denotes the ceiling function, for $a_2$ $E(5/2)$ choices etc, so you have exactly $E(11/2) E(6/2) E(3/2) E(2/2)E(2/2) = 6\cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 = 36 $ choices, for $11 \cdot 6 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 = $something I don't want to compute divisors hence
$$P = \frac{6\cdot 3 \cdot 2}{11 \cdot 6 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 2} = \frac{1}{22}$$